# mySQL syntax error, but there is no error?

Tags: mysql, sql

It keep getting this SQL error, but I am very certain there are no errors in the query. I have been staring at it too long. Is there something else that might cause this?

```
INSERT INTO game_data (clue, image, answer, wrong, right) VALUES ('asdf',         'asdf', 'asdf', 'assdf', 'asdf')

Invalid Query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right) VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'assdf', 'asdf')' at line 1
```

I have run other queries with this exact code, just swapping out the variables, and it works.

and for good measure, there is the php that generates this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO game_data (clue, image, answer, wrong, right) VALUES
    ('" . $clue . "', '" . $image . "', '" . $answer . "', '" . $wrong . "', '" . $right . "')";
```

Comment: Incidentally, what kind of value goes in `wrong` and/or `right`? Also, all those ". things are unnecessary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**right** is a [reserved keyword in MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html). You need to escape it using backticks like this:

```
INSERT INTO game_data (`clue`, `image`, `answer`, `wrong`, `right`) VALUES
```

**Note:** Try to avoid naming your columns as reserved keyword names in future.

Comment: @RobH:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The name 'right' is a MySQL reserved keyword. I dont know how can you create 'right' column.

Comment: ...well, by enclosing it in back ticks- but better to avoid reserved words altogether